# Is MySQL's `ORDER BY` distinct on multisets?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

Assuming a table with a column where integers are stored.

```
-----------------------------
id    |  some_int  | some_other_value
-----------------------------
1        5           hello
2        9           how
3        987         are
4        5           you
5        9           thanks
6        1           for
7        5           answering. :-)
```

Is `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY some_int;` distinct? Meaning will it always return the rows in the same order, after each query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge if there are duplicates in the order by clause, there is no guarantee for the order in which the duplicates are presented.

If this is a concern, you could modify the order by to include the primary key (id I am assuming).

```
ORDER BY some_int, id
```

Since id is a primary key, it should also be indexed.  Thus the performance difference will be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this order by does not always have to give you the same result order. It is not frequent that the order will be different but it's not a 100% safe to assume that the order will always be the same as it is not an unique value that you're ordering by. To achieve this you should also include the primary key after the initial order.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY some_int, id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY some_int,id;
```

So it will sort for 'some_int' and then using 'id' Duplicates for 'some_id' will be set to fixed position using 'id' column